# Exception: No item with the given ID could be found. Possibly because you have not edited this item or you do not have permission to access it

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-forms

I have the following setup:

- It is a GAS Google Forms addon
- It requests various scopes: send email, current google form, google spreadsheets etc.
- It sets an installable "on form submit" trigger

Most of the time everything works as intended, but sometimes I get this error message: "Exception: No item with the given ID could be found. Possibly because you have not edited this item or you do not have permission to access it."

I have tried the following to reproduce this situation, but in vain:

- Disable the addon within the document (can be done with the help of the "Use in this document" setting) --> in this case the trigger gets "disabled" and the "on form submit" function is not called
- Remove the access for the addon within "My Google Account" --> in this case the "on form submit" function is not called

Any ideas?

---

Attached is the minimum code of my installable on form submit handler.
It seems, that reading the document properties causes the error.
Although I should be allowed to read these properties as the function is running in `AuthMode.FULL` mode.

```
function onSubmitInst(event) {
    console.log(event.authMode === ScriptApp.AuthMode.FULL); // In case of error --> logs always true

    console.log(ScriptApp.getAuthorizationInfo(ScriptApp.AuthMode.FULL).authInfo.getAuthorizationStatus().toString()); // In case of error --> sometimes "REQUIRED", sometimes "NOT_REQUIRED"

    var docProps = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties(); // In case of error --> "Exception: No item with the given ID could be found. Possibly because you have not edited this item or you do not have permission to access it."

    // Other code following ...
}
```

Comment: @JShinigami - I would report it to the issue tracker, seems like a bug. But first, what is your daily rate of fire for the trigger?

Comment: @OlegValter: The users who are facing this issue fire this trigger between 5 and 10 times a day. I halso have the impression that it is a bug. I assume these users have already disabled / uninstalled / removed access the addon, but the "on form submit" trigger is still firing.

Comment: @OlegValter It is a public GAS addon published on Google Workspace Marketplace. I have tried it out: if I uninstall my addon, the triggers are also deleted. But it seems that sometimes this does not work properly. I had a look at Google Cloud Platform Logging and filtered by the user-ID of these users. I can only see these error log entries, and no "onOpen" log entries (I am logging these function calls). Which is an additional indicator that the addon might be already uninstalled.

Comment: @OlegValter Yes the form submit trigger runs regardless of opening the form. What I tried to say: Usually my users open the form from time to time / usually on a daily basis to check the status of the survey. So if I filter by one user-ID in the logging tool I usually see a mixture of onOpen and onFormSubmit log entries. But in these cases I can only see onFormSubmit log entries, which means onOpen does not fire anymore --> reason could be: 1) addon already uninstalled 2) users are really not opening the form

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224468/discussion-between-oleg-valter-and-jshinigami).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following situation produces the error:

- User A has access to the form and activates the addon / on form submit trigger
- User B has also access to the form
- User A gets removed from the form (IMPORTATN: the trigger does still exist within his/her environment: https://script.google.com/home/triggers)
- User B continues to make surveys, let's say user C submits the form
- The remaining trigger from User A fires and produces the error

Answer (score 2):

I'm wondering if the error ocurrs to form collaborators (form editors, not the owner) that have not edited the form.

What about this "workaround"?

On your add-on function that creates the trigger using a try...catch try to get the Document properties. If there is an error, insert a question then remove it.

Disclaimer: I didn't tried this so before incluiding this on your public add-on you might want to publish a copy as unlisted / only for your domain for testing purposes.

Comment: Can you please describe the workaround with more details? I understand the try/catch part, but what do you mean by "insert a question then remove it"?

Comment: @JShinigami I mean  edit the form. Inserting a question and deleting it inmediately at the end this will only make that the form last modification date be updated. Disclaimer I didn't tried did so before incluiding this on your public add-on you might want to publish a copy for testing purposes.