# Exception: No item with the given ID could be found. you do not have permission to access it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

We're randomly getting this error for some of our users.
We're trying to access form by using this function

```
 const form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
```

Here is the image of cloud error

[image]

Not able to understand where the issue is.
Any help is appriciated

Comment: Is the Apps Script [bound](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) to the form? Or is a [standalone](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone) script? Is the Form share with the user that are getting error messages? Is the issue happening randomly for the affected users, or does it always happen to the same users?

Comment: Does the user have an open Form?

Comment: The script is bound to the form as the user uses us as a addon. No, the form is created by the user only. It happens to someone users only and then repeat for them only. `Does the user have an open Form?` what do you mean by `open form`

Answer (score 0):

I was investigating this issue and I found some information that might help you.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64798671) with 2 valid answers.

The first answer:

> The following situation produces the error:
>
> - User A has access to the form and activates the addon / on form submit trigger
> - User B has also access to the form
> - User A gets removed from the form (IMPORTANT: the trigger does still exist within his/her environment: https://script.google.com/home/triggers)
> - User B continues to make surveys, let's say user C submits the form
>   The remaining trigger from User A fires and produces the error

The second answer:

> I'm wondering if the error occurs to form collaborators (form editors, not the owner) that have not edited the form.
>
> What about this "workaround"?
>
> On your add-on function that creates the trigger using a try... catch try to get the Document properties. If there is an error, insert a question, then remove it.

Another thing I found [here](https://qiita.com/toro_ponz/items/c32365a368e43113f031), is that the error might be related to: **"The script was failing to run due to insufficient privileges granted to it"**

> This access is granted through the authorization window of what is in the OAuth scope when setting up the trigger.
>
> 1. [Missing OAuth](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849#userconsent) scopes for the project.
> 2. Third-party apps are created with [insufficient permissions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#viewing_scopes) granted when setting triggers.
> 3. Error when fired.

Lastly, I found an [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/36755036) but with the `FormApp.openById`. If you test all the things above, your users are having issues. I will say to open a new issue tracker [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#problems_errors)

Comment: [@Chirag Gupta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11591977/chirag-gupta), If this answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. how to accept answer (https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: No it did not solved my issue @Giselle Valladares

Comment: @ChiragGupta in that case, I will suggest to create an issue tracker if the issue persist [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#problems_errors) or contact Google support if you have a Workspace subscription.